# ¿Por qué aparece un signo de porcentaje (%) al terminar de ejecutar mi programa en linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Cuando termino de crear el código; digamos este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  
  int n;
  int n5 = 0 ,n3 = 0 ;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("Pone un numero: ");
    scanf(" %d",&n);

    if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0){
      n3++;
      n5++;

    }else if(n % 3 == 0) {
      n3++;

    }else if(n % 5 == 0) {
      n5++;

    }
  }
  printf("De 3 : %d\n\nDe 5 : %d",n3,n5);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Hago esto --> `gcc 1-for.c -o 1-for`

Después lo ejecuto con `./1-for`

Y cuando termina el código, me aparece asi.

```
De 3 : 1

De 5 : 0%
```

Yo lo que quiero que no aparezca es el símbolo de `%`. No se porque me aparece, y me aparece en todos los ejercicios que hice.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres sacar es el porcentaje de qué?

Comment: yo quiero sacar el simbolo del %, porque me aparece sin que yo lo pida.
El codigo es literal, el que esta ahi, y el output de ese codigo es el de abajo. 
No tengo idea porque me aparece el "%". Esto me aparece unicamente cuando lo ejecuto desde mi terminal linux

Comment: Agrega un `\n` al final de la línea, después del segundo `%d`

Comment: sos el 1, gracias.

Comment: @Rodrigo, escribí una respuesta, para que quede documentado. Un saludo y no olvides hacer el [tour].

Answer (score 5):

El símbolo de `%` que ves al final es agregado automáticamente por el *shell* para indicar que la salida del programa no terminó en una línea nueva, sino que había una *línea parcial*. Zsh no utiliza esa línea, sino que inicia una nueva para evitar mezclar allí el *prompt*.

Para que no aparezca, terminá siempre el programa en una línea nueva, por ejemplo, agregando un `\n` al final de la única salida que tiene:

```
printf("De 3 : %d\n\nDe 5 : %d\n", n3, n5);
```

La [documentación de prompting](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#Prompting) dice:

> When a partial line is preserved, by default you will see an inverse+bold character at the end of the partial line: a ‘%’ for a normal user or a ‘#’ for root. If set, the shell parameter PROMPT_EOL_MARK can be used to customize how the end of partial lines are shown.

Mi traducción libre sería:

> Cuándo se preserva una línea parcial, por defecto verás un caracter *inverso+negrilla* al final de la línea parcial: Un ‘%’ para usuarios normales y un ‘#’ para el *root*. Si se establece, el parámetro del shell PROMPT_EOL_MARK puede ser utilizado para personalizar cómo se muestra el final de líneas parciales.

**Edición**:

Gracias a Marcos por dejar el link a [esta otra respuesta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167600/21764), esta vez en el sitio **Unix & Linux** de la red, que contenía un link a la documentación oficial.

Mi texto original decía:

Como es habitual, quise agregar algún link a documentación oficial, pero lo único que encontré fue [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53932652/255257) de StackOverflow en inglés.

Comment: @Marcos, hecho, ya está editada la respuesta. Gracias por el dato!